# Tidy dataFrame with pandas to remove canceled orders?

Tags: python, pandas

New to pandas and python in general. Can not figure out how to "tidy" the dataframe to remove canceled orders.

For example dataframe looks like this :

```
ID  OrderID  New/Cancel Amount
0   1259           N    1   
1   1259           C        
2   1260           N    1
3   1260           C        
4   1261           N    1
5   1261           C        
6   1263           N       1
7   1277           N       1
8   1280           N       1
```

OrderID 1259 was a New order, which was later canceled. How can I "tidy" the dataframe, or create a new dataframe with clean data?
In the above case what I should end up with is just the last three orders (1263, 1277, 1280) since they where not "C" which stands for canceled. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of `OrderID`s which contain a cancellation order, and perform a [`boolean indexation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) on `df` using [`.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
m = df.loc[df['New/Cancel'] == 'C', 'OrderID']
df[~df.OrderID.isin(m)]

   ID    OrderID New/Cancel  Amount
6   6     1263          N     1.0
7   7     1277          N     1.0
8   8     1280          N     1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `groupby` + `transform` with a custom function:

```
df = df[df.groupby('OrderID')['New/Cancel'].transform(lambda x: (x != 'C').all())]

print(df)

   ID  OrderID New/Cancel  Amount
6   6     1263          N     1.0
7   7     1277          N     1.0
8   8     1280          N     1.0
```